# Results changed on all clicked fields

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have made a setup for a 3 way binding, but there is one issue I'm struggling with.

The workflow is like this, an object is selected in an array which is then loaded in input fields from where I can change the object and it's reflected in the array list to.

The problem is that when I click on another object in the array the data on the objects gets changed just by clicking on new ones..

here is my code.

The html part.

```
<input ng-model="data.name" value="{{data.name}}" class="nobackground">
<input ng-model="data.article" value="{{data.article}}" class="nobackground">
<input ng-model="data.filepath" value="{{data.filepath}}" class="nobackground">
```

Controller.

```
$scope.loadModel = function($id) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://---.firebaseio.com/models/"+$id);
    var syncObject = $firebaseObject(ref);
    syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "data");

    };
```

And for the list part.

Html

```
<div ng-repeat="($id, item) in list | filter:clientFilter | filter:name "class="col-md-3" style="height: 300px;">
<a href="" ng-click="loadModel(item.$id)"><img src="img/a0320101.0001.jpg" width="250" height="250"></a>
<p>{{ item.name }} {{ item.article }} {{ item.filepath }} {{ item.published | date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}</p>
<div>
<button ng-click="removeModel($id)">delete</button>
</div>
</div>
```

And the list controller.

```
var list = $firebaseArray(new Firebase('https://---.firebaseio.com/models'));
$scope.list = list;
```

Comment: I have a hard time parsing your problem: "The problem is that when I click on another object in the array the data on the objects gets changed just by clicking on new ones." Is there any way you can rephrase that? Alternatively: can you set up a minimal reproduction of your problem on jsfiddle/jsbin?

Comment: Sorry for that, its like this. If i click item 1 it Opens the data for item 1 in the input fields, then if i change the text there its updated as it should, but if I then click item 2 then the data from item 2 is added to item 1, and if i change the text after selecting nr 2 both items get edited, let me know if thats still not clear!

Comment: Do you `unbind` the object anywhere? See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-bindtoscope-varname

Comment: No i have missed that will look ok that today!

Comment: I tried using unbind but the issue still seems to be there.
I think you can try the issue very easy, if you open an object in input fields(without using bind) then type in one of the fields on the opened object, then when you open a new object in the input fields the value you typed will still be there, not the data from the new object.
I can do it in a fiddle if I'm not explaining it good enough?

Comment: Solved, it was the unbind issue!

Comment: Great. Now if you post how you solved the problem, people might benefit from your experience in the future. Self-answers are encouraged here at StackOverflow, specifically for that reason. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What was missing in my 3-way binging was the unbind part, that releases the object from the scope when a new one is clicked.

Here is how I solved it.

```
var unbindModel = function(){};

$scope.loadModel = function($id) {

    unbindModel();

    var ref = new Firebase("https://----.firebaseio.com/models/"+$id);

    var syncObject = $firebaseObject(ref);
    syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "data").then(function(unbind) {
    unbindModel = unbind;




 });
```

Now everytime the button is clicked it runs the unbind if it has been bound before.